# How to run JS files using NodeJS?

Tags: external-calls, javascript

I have installed NodeJS.

[image]

And I ran the comci.js file.
comci.js file URL ( http://naver.me/5MUV22Uj  )

[image]

After that, I entered the command getTimeTable according to the format and executed it. However, the result of command execution is not displayed. What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You had defined your functions under `module.exports`, use this code:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "module.exports.getTimeTable(1,1,1)"]
```

or remove `module.exports` from `.js` file and use it directly:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "getTimeTable(1,1,1)"]
```